# Can I use random choice to choose between 2 functions

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm trying to create a function that randomly picks a number and then randomly adds or subtracts 1 from the chosen number but it seems that the random.choice function isn't working the way it is supposed to do I'm getting output but it's not the result of adding or subtracting (I visualized it on Thonny)
Here is my code

```
import random
def addsubone(x):
 result=0
 n= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 x=random.choice(n)
 def adding(x):
   x=x+1
 def substracting(x):
   x=x-1
 random.choice([adding,substracting])
 return(x)
print(addsubone(0))
```

Comment: You assigned the return value of `random.choice(n)`, so why you didn't do the same with `random.choice([adding,substracting])`? You should also `return x` from both functions, and you also never **called** the chosen function

Comment: although the error is obviously that you don't assign your random choice to anything it would be better to randomly chose between [-1, 1] and add the result to x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are objects that can be assigned to variables like any other object. To randomly chose one, make a random choice from a list of functions. See below.

Your function ignores its argument `x`, I removed it entirely.

Recommendation: do not define constants in a function. Each time you call the functions they will be uselessly re-defined.

```
import random

NUMBERS = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def adding(x):
    return x+1

def substracting(x):
    return x-1

FUNCTIONS = [adding, substracting]

def addsubone():
    n = random.choice(NUMBERS)
    f = random.choice(FUNCTIONS)
    return f(n)

print(addsubone())
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!! I also didn't return x after each def that's a huge mistake!